# php POST inserted into javascript

Tags: javascript, php, geocoding

Im trying to use the address from a form input that is in the POST and insert that adress into this javascript for geocoding it into a pin point on the map. I put the POST into a javscript variable but i cant seem to get that into the function that geodoces it.
here is it live on a test site http://nickshanekearney.com/geo/

```
<?php $address = $_POST["address"]; ?>
<script> 
var address = "<?php echo $_POST["address"]; ?>";
var geocoder;
var map;

function codeAddress() {
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
}
</script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: see the double quotes (`"`) here `var address = "<?php echo $_POST["address"]; ?>";`. It's an error writing

Comment: Try to replace with `var address = "<?php echo $_POST['address']; ?>";`

Comment: with  double quotes , it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the address as argument to your function like this :

```
<?php $address = $_POST["address"]; ?>
<script> 
var address = "<?php echo $_POST["address"]; ?>";
var geocoder;
var map;

function codeAddress(address) {

geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
    });

    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
    service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
  } else {
    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
  }
});
}
</script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

Comment: This is all good advice im so close you can see here my progress http://nickshanekearney.com/geo/

It works now but not on load I have to press the submit button twice. is it because I need to start the function on load instead of on submit of form?

Answer (score 2):

I think you have an error in `quotes` writing.
See your line below:

```
var address = "<?php echo $_POST["address"]; ?>";
```

---

**it must be** :

```
 var address = "<?php echo $_POST['address']; ?>";
```

**or**

```
var address = "<?php echo $address; ?>";// because you already declared variable $address at the top of your source code
```

And the variable `address` that you declared is overwritten when you call `codeAddress()` function.
So clear this line too :

```
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
```

Or **if you are using it**,you have to check if the posted variable exist or not :

```
function codeAddress(){
<?php 
if (isset($_POST['address'])){
echo "var address = $_POST['address'];"; 
}
else{
echo "var address = document.getElementById('address').value;";
}

?>

...
```

Comment: var address = "<?php echo $_POST["address"]; ?>";
this works too

Answer (score 1):

Just remove this line:

```
var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
```

Because it overwrites the `address` you already declared on the third line.

Answer (score 1):

It is so strange that you echo the value to JS, but your JS gets the address from element with ID = `address`, overwritten your PHP-echoed result.

You probably want:

```
function codeAddress() {
  var address = "<?php echo $_POST['address']; ?>";
  geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: results[0].geometry.location
      });

      infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
      var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
      service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
    } else {
      alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
    }
  });
}
</script>
```